# How do I make a 404 error instead of a cast error

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a route that is `/mysafe/idofthemodel.` When the `idofthemodel` isn't found it throws a cast error `Cast to ObjectId failed for value "something" (type string) at path "_id" for model "modelname".` Instead of the error I would like to have a 404 error.

Here is my route

```html
app.get('/mysafe/:safeid',isLoggedIn,isAuthor, async(req,res)=> {
    const { safeid } = req.params;
    
    const safe=await Safe.findById(safeid).populate('author')
    const password = await Password.find({safe:safeid}).populate('safe')
    
    res.render('passwords/index', { password,safe })
})
```

Schemas:

```
const PasswordsSchema = new Schema({
    title: String,
    url: String,
    password: String,
    safe: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "Safe"
    },
})
const SafeSchema = new Schema({
    author: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "User"
    },
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here I'm using EJS to render the 404 Error page,
and the page file is located in views/errors/404.ejs

```
    const { safeid } = req.params;

    try {
        const safe = await Safe.findOne({ _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(safeid) }).populate('author')

        if (!safe) {
            return res.status(404).render('errors/404.ejs')
        }

        const password = await Password.findOne({ safe: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(safeid) }).populate('safe')
        return res.render('passwords/index', { password, safe })

    }
    catch (error) {
        return res.status(500).render('errors/500')
    }
```

middleware.js

```
module.exports.isAuthor = (req, res, next) => {
    const { safeid } = req.params

    if (!mongoose.Types.ObjectId.isValid(safeid)) {
        return res.status(404).render('errors/404.ejs')
    }

    Safe.findById(safeid).then(safe => {
        if (!safe) {
            return res.status(404).render('errors/404.ejs')
        }
        if (!safe.author._id.equals(req.user._id)) {
            req.flash('error', 'Notfound');
            return res.redirect('/');
        }
        next();
    });
}
```

Comment: it still throws a cast error. it something with the _id. but thanks for the help appreciate it

Comment: can you share the Safe model and the safeId param ?

Comment: So its an app where a user has a safe and in that safe he has passwords. Every user has its own safe with a id and a password has a id and is in that safe

Comment: add the edits to the main question.

Comment: try putting the password line after the if condition as in last edit,
and share the error here.

Comment: still the same error                                                                                                                         Cast to ObjectId failed for value "" (type string) at path "_id" for model "Safe"